# Managed object not deleted properly in my core database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am trying to delete some objects from my `Entity Reservation`. I am doing it like this.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = reservation.managedObjectContext;
[context deleteObject:reservation];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
}
```

After that I delete my object I fetch the whole `entity` again. I can see that the object is delete from my `entity`. But when I restart my app, all my objects that I deleted in the previous session are back stored in my `entity`.

I'm using `restkit` to store my objects that I got back from a webservice. Also when I delete the object, I delete it also in my database.

When I restart my app and look at my logs I see that I don't get the object back from my webservice that I deleted in the previous session, so that's oké. The only problem is that they are somehow stored back in my `core database`.

Comment: Is your delete happening in a background thread? I don't think your persistant store is being updated when you delete the object, if this is happening on a background thread make sure you merge changes with mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:

Comment: What do you mean with merge changes ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how reskit handles saving/deleting on threads but basically when you setup your NSManagedObjectContext on the main thread you register for notifications.

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)aContext
{
   if (!_aContext) {
       _aContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
   }
   return _aContext;
}
```

If a change to context happens on a background thread then a notification will be sent.

```
-(void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
 // Merge the changes from the notification
 // on the main thread as this is the main
 // context for our application.
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.aContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:aNotification];
 });
}
```

Comment: Yes it should be fine. Maybe also have a look at the docs. http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html#//api/name/savesToPersistentStore